# How to send photo on telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

i'm just implementing a simple bot who should send some photos and videos to my `chat_id`. 
Well, i'm using python, this is the script

```
import sys
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print 'Got command: %s' % command

    if command == 'command1':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, *******)
    elif command == 'command2':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, ******)
    elif command == 'photo':
        bot.sendPhoto(...)

bot = telepot.Bot('*** INSERT TOKEN ***')
bot.message_loop(handle)
print 'I am listening ...'

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

In the line `bot.sendphoto` I would insert the path and the `chat_id` of my image but nothing happens.

Where am I wrong?

thanks

Comment: Could you post the exact call to `sendPhoto()`? And please fix the indentation in your posted code.

Comment: it may be so helpful if you tell about the `telegram response` to your request

Answer (score 36):

If you have local image path:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=open('path', 'rb'))
```

If you have url of image from internet:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id, 'your URl')
```

Comment: It is bot.sendPhoto not bot.send_photo

Comment: @BiplobDas https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo

Answer (score 23):

Just using the ***Requests*** lib you can do it:

```
def send_photo(chat_id, file_opened):
    method = "sendPhoto"
    params = {'chat_id': chat_id}
    files = {'photo': file_opened}
    resp = requests.post(api_url + method, params, files=files)
    return resp

send_photo(chat_id, open(file_path, 'rb'))
```

Comment: there are error in api_url

Comment: api_url is not a var, is a string you must put

Answer (score 9):

I have used the following command while using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) to send the image along with a caption:

```
 context.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=
"url_of_image", caption="This is the test photo caption")
```

Answer (score 7):

I've tried also sending from python using requests. Maybe it's late answer, but leaving this here for others like me.. maybe it'll come to use..
I succeded with `subprocess` like so:

```
def send_image(botToken, imageFile, chat_id):
        command = 'curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot' + botToken + '/sendPhoto -F chat_id=' + chat_id + " -F photo=@" + imageFile
        subprocess.call(command.split(' '))
        return
```

Answer (score 7):

#### This is complete code to send a photo in telegram:

> ```
> import telepot
> bot = telepot.Bot('______ YOUR TOKEN ________')
>
> # here replace chat_id and test.jpg with real things
> bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo=open('test.jpg', 'rb'))
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass 2 params

```
bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, 'URL')
```

Answer (score 2):

[sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) requires at least two parameters; first one is target *chat_id*, and for second one *photo* you have three options:

1. Pass [file_id](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) if the photo is already uploaded to telegram servers (recommended because you don't need to reupload it).
2. If the photo is uploaded somewhere else, pass the full http url and telegram will download it (max photo size is 5MB atm).
3. Post the file using multipart/form-data like you want to upload it via a browser (10MB max photo size this way).