# python-telegram-bot - send_photo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I got this error while sending a photo:

```
Bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=update.effective_user.id,photo=open(f'{os.getcwd()}\\{update.effective_user.id}\\{i}', 'rb'))
TypeError: send_photo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have no idea how to set `self` there, I wrote the code according to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778321/how-to-send-photo-on-telegram-bot), and I sat `chat_id` and `photo`. Also I used `.sendPhoto` I don't know why i get `send_photo()` error. Is it a bug or somthing i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an instance of `Bot()` not `Bot` ,

e.g. `bot = Bot()`
and then do `bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=update.effective_user.id,photo=open(f'{os.getcwd()}\\{update.effective_user.id}\\{i}', 'rb'))`

Comment: bot = Bot(token) you meant, pog anyway

Comment: Sure, pass whatever parameters are required to instantiate `Bot(...)`